# Search text input for occurences of words from list in database

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a MySQL table with a list of bad words in it (bad_words), and I want to scan a text field (public_message) for the number of bad words in that field. There are about 1100 entries in bad_words

I've tried contains, but that only looks at one word.

Something like this:

`SELECT public_post_id, count(word)
FROM public_posts
WHERE public_message CONTAINS (SELECT word FROM bad_words)`

I know this syntax is wrong, but that's the gist of what I'm trying to achieve.

The final output should be a number of bad words in each public_message. I'm not concerned with which words at this point, just if there are any, and how many.

Comment: You need a "full text search" extension to be installed in MySQL.

Comment: Any one in particular that you would recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT p.public_post_id, COUNT(*)
FROM public_posts p JOIN bad_words b
  ON public_message LIKE CONCAT('%', b.word, '%')
```

But it will have incredibly bad performance. It will have to do a number of searches equal to the number of rows in `public_posts` *times* the 1,100 words in `bad_words`.

MySQL has a feature for fulltext indexing, but it won't work for your case.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-restrictions.html says:

> The argument to AGAINST() must be a string value that is constant during query evaluation. This rules out, for example, a table column because that can differ for each row.

In other words, you **can't** do this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM public_posts p JOIN bad_words b
 ON MATCH(p.public_posts) AGAINST(b.word) -- ERROR!
```

You could search for one word at a time, but then it would require 1,100 queries.

Or you could do it with a fulltext index by listing many words in the AGAINST expression:

```
SELECT ...
FROM public_posts p
WHERE MATCH(p.public_posts) AGAINST('word1 word2 word3 word4 word5...' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

The many words could be a list you generate by querying the `bad_words` table.

But this doesn't tell you the count of matches per word, only that the post contained at least one matching word.

Also, I'm not sure if there's a length limit, or if you can make a string of all 1,100 bad words.

I don't know of any other fulltext search implementation that would handle this better.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response Bill. What if we did it the other way? That is to say, only search for bad words in ONE public_post at a time?

Comment: It would have the same problems.